# Reposting a Question from Math.stackexchange on Stats.stackexchange? Specifically one about probability?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I posted a question over at math.stackexchange involving the probability of all 
TRUE scenarios that fit the constraints I establish.

A link is here (assuming I'm allowed to link to it here to provide context):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395394/solving-ptrue-of-finding-counterpart-pairs-in-2-sets-with-constraints-involvin

Seeing as it's about probability...and I'm a bit confused about this...is it OK or acceptable to also post the question here?

I get a feeling there are rules generally against such a thing, but I could not find them.

Comment: Your feeling is correct insofar as cross-posting is explicitly discouraged on Stack Exchange. Concisely from https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

"Please note ... that cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated."  
 In your case, there are no answers as I write and you've offered a bounty of 100. If you get no answers there, I would delete and repost here.  (Giving the link as evidence is more than fine.)

Comment: I've edited in the tag `cross-posting` and from looking at posts under that heading I think this can be declared a duplicate.

Comment: @NickCox Why does the cross-posting tag exist then?  It seems as everything under the cross-posting tag would then be a duplicate question to the original one you reference.

Thank you for the appropriate advice on what to do if I don't get answers on math.sx though.

Comment: @Taal *meta* is a place to discuss policy so having a crossposting tag there makes sense -- it's fine to ask questions *about* crossposting on meta. And crossposts are at least *sometimes* okay -- Andy W's answer at the duplicate lists a potential exception and I list another here.

Comment: The cross-posting tag exists because people ask about cross-posting, just as you have done. This is the difference between Meta and the main site. People don't read the Help carefully enough or -- more interestingly -- find it unclear or ambiguous. So questions are asked.

Comment: @NickCox Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the first page of the help -- [help/on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), third-last paragraph says:

> Please note, however, that cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated.

And broadly speaking, this is the position. However, it's mitigated somewhat by meta-posts here that suggest that if you expect different *kinds* of answers (e.g. seeking legal aspects of a question vs interpersonal aspects would each be on topic in their respective SE sites); in that case the kinds of answers sought would be fundamentally different and we'd see that as reasonable.

Comment: (+1) And best to tailor the question so that it makes your expectation clear. Buy goodwill by including a link to the duplicate on the other site - it's discourteous not to.

Comment: @Scortchi This is good advice, thank you.

Comment: I didn't explicitly state it (thinking it obvious) but it would be rare for a question posted to stats.SE and math.SE to actually be seeking different kinds of answers

Comment: @Scortchi What if I do not want to include a link to the other question so as to potentially bias the answers differently than the way I want them (which is out of context).  IE. on Math I ended up giving away the entire context of the problem towards the end as the one person trying to solve it I was trying to help as much as possible & just went for it

Comment: @Taal: Tough! Remember you're asking for people to give up their free time to help you. Suppose you help your next-door neighbour fill in his tax return. Then you find out that he's already had the neighbour on the other side help - he wants to double-check it. Or that he's asked everyone on the street - he's conducting some kind of an experiment on variability. You'd be peeved. Most you could decently do is link to the other question & *ask* if people would mind not looking at it if they want to answer it here.

Comment: Orthogonally to that, I'd have thought if answers to a question on maths/statistics can be "biased" by providing the context, it's an indication that the question's unclear in the first place.

Comment: @Scortchi I know how I can resolve my issue while still providing a link...i'd just provide a link to the question in its original form.  I was never going to not mention it was on math already though.  



 My bounty just expired...

Ah maybe i'll post it maybe not.  We'll see.  The person working on it or thinking about it now is an active member on both sites though (as are most people it seems).

Comment: @Scortchi The guy working on the question didn't use the context I gave him at the end by the way, he said he liked it in its mathematical form purely too.  So I although you mention it's an indication....it's just an indication...not a truth.

Comment: Sorry if my comment above seemed accusatory - I just wanted to make my point firmly for anyone who might read it. Personally I'd give the question a bit more time on Math SE before thinking about deleting it & re-posting here.